# IE Only: When toggling visibility of an element, adjacent content does not refresh until moused over

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

So I'm using .show() and .hide() to well, show and hide some elements on my page on certain triggers.  Say I have 3 divs on top of eachother and I expand the top one, the content from one of the bottom ones doesn't seem to move until I mouseover it.  I'm having this happen in multiple projects with totally different layouts.  Is there a generic cause/fix for this?

After clicking "expand":

[image: After clicking "expand"]

After moving my mouse over the element:

[image: After moving my mouse over the element]

**Javascript:**

```
    //expand details per container
    $('.Trigger').live('click', function () {
        var thisid = $(this).attr('toggletrigger');
        if ($(thisid).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(thisid).show();
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url("../Content/themes/base/images/btn_expandcollapse_small-2.png")');
        } else {
            $(thisid).hide();
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url("../Content/themes/base/images/btn_expandcollapse_small-1.png")');
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="Trigger" toggletrigger=".GeneralHidden">

<div class="Section">
    <span class="GeneralHidden Hidden">
        //other stuff here that *shouldn't* be relevant.
    </span>
</div>

<div class="Section">
    //other stuff here that *shouldn't* be relevant.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Hidden             {display: none;}
.GeneralHidden      {}
.Section            {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
                     padding-top:5px;
                     background-color: #FBFBFB;
                     border: 1px solid #FBFBFB;
                     border-left: 3px solid gray;}
.Section:hover      {background-color: White; border: 1px solid gray; border-left: 3px solid gray;}
```

I've confirmed it's something to do with the

```
            <div class="Section">
                This is a test.
            </div>
```

^^^ Adding this code after an expandable item works properly.

```
            <div class="Section">
                <fieldset>
                This is a test.
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

^^^ Adding this code exhibits the same errant behavior as before.  I have NO css applied to fieldsets.

Comment: Please post the code you are using. My first guess would this be either due to CSS floating of the hide/show elements, or possibly a margin/padding bug in jQuery.

Comment: okay... added everything I think is relevant.  There's a lot more CSS and HTML in between that would be too much to post I think.  Nothing out of the ordinary besides <fieldset>

Comment: It's the content of the lower "section" that isn't updating (the "section" itself does move).

Comment: Confirmed it's something to do with <fieldset>.  See end of OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just seems to be an issue with using the fieldset tag.  Works fine without it.